# React + ASP.Net Core 3: CORS Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-3.0

I am trying to set up a react front end to talk to a .net back end. However I seem to be stuck on cors set up. Below I have my startup code from the back end project as well as the code from my front end. I've followed multiple guides and I am not sure where I am messing up, this worked on my localhost previously but not when deployed to cloud. (guides I am following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1 and https://code-maze.com/enabling-cors-in-asp-net-core/)

Thanks for the help!

Error from React App console:
Access to fetch at 'https://backend.azurewebsites.net/api/accountcredentials' from origin 'https://frontend.azurewebsites.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Startup code in asp.net project:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson();

        services.AddSingleton<UserService>();
        services.AddSingleton<AccountService>();

        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("ReactPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin() //dev
                   //.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3007") // dev
                   //.WithOrigins("https://frontend.azurewebsites.net")
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowCredentials();
        }));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapControllers();
        });

        app.UseCors("ReactPolicy");

        app.UseAuthorization();
    }
```

Attributes on controller class:

```
  [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [EnableCors("ReactPolicy")]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this way :

```
    readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
            builder =>
            {
                builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(isOriginAllowed: _ => true).AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials();
            });
        });

        ...
     }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env)
    {

        ...

        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor |
                   ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });

        app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

        ...

    }
```

edit `MyAllowSpecificOrigins` to your cors name

Comment: YURSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS!!!! THANK YOU!